# MongoDb $slice not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to fetch some records using aggregate function in MongoDB, 
 but it show following invalid operator `$slice`:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate( [
    { $match: { 'subjectId': '123' } }, 
    { $sort: { 'assessmentDate': -1 } }, 
    { $group: { '_id': '$area', 'docs': { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },  
    { $project: { docs: { $slice: ["$docs", 1, 1]   }  }  }, 
])
```

---

```
Error("Printing Stack Trace")@:0()@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37([objectArray])@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:866
@(shell):1
uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$slice'",
    "code" : 15999,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

MongoDB version 3.0.9

Comment: `$slice` working from MongoDB 3.2

Comment: yes, it worked , MogoDb version should be 3.2.x aboveThanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use $slice we should use mongoDB version above 3.2.x,
Change log can be found on [changelog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-changelog/).

Documentation for $slice [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/)